# How to repair broken HDMI port on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, repair

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015). I'm happy with it but recently I started having problems connecting my external screen via HDMI.

Since a few days ago, I can't make it work anymore at all and I found the problem: Looking into the HDMI connector at my MacBook, I can see that one of the silver wires of the connector is "bent away", i.e. instead of being flat and aligned with all the others, it's bent toward the rear end of the connector. No wonder the screen doesn't work.

I believe the HDMI port is botched for good, because if I somehow managed to move those connectors down, plugging in the cable would just move them out of place again.

Hence: Is it possible to swap the HDMI port by myself? I have no problem opening the MacBook and if it's just a tedious task, I can do it.
If that port is properly mounted to the mainboard and cannot be swapped by itself, how much would a swap roughly be at an AppleStore (Germany)?

Here's a photo: [image: photo of port]

Comment: It is possible, but these things are usually always more involved than you initially might think. There's a guide in ifixit: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Early+2015+I-O+Board+Replacement/45132 — And just for good measure, it might be good to know they have a pretty nifty multi-page menu which should always lead to what you need pretty easily, assuming they have a guide for it ( https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro ). — You should ask the apple store how much it costs. There might also be those third-party repair shops that do it for way cheaper.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link! I didn't know it, but meanwhile also a colleague told me about it.
Looking at it, it seems I have to swap the I/O Board which I easily available second-hand and I will will need some heat-conductive paste during reassembling.
The instructions look good. It'll take a bit but it's worth it and I'll give it a try. Thanks!